# Error downloading youtube-dlp: SSL handshake failed

Tags: ssl, youtube-dl

After i upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04. i am receiving this error while downloading ClipGrab **"Error downloading youtube-dlp: SSL handshake failed"**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Running kubuntu 22.04. Same SSL handshake error.

Here is the fix that worked for me.

Download the `yt-dlp` file from:

https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp#release-files

The `yt-dlp` file found on that page it's the first file in the recommended listing column.

On your computer:

Allow your file manager to show hidden directories/files. Or navigate with the terminal.

Navigate to `/home/user/.local/share/ClipGrab/ClipGrab/yt-dlp`

Overwrite the existing file - which will be there but empty - with the file you downloaded from the link above.

Start ClipGrab up and it will work.